# pass functions and their parameters to child component

Tags: angular

I have a parent component with a function that takes a parameter:

```js
parentFunc(parm: any): boolean {
    // do something with the parm
}
```

And part of its template is:

```html
<app-child [func]="parentFunc(123)"></app-child>
```

In the child component:

```
@Input('func') func: any => boolean;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.func)
        this.func(/* what should be put here? */);
}
```

Basically the child accepts a function reference and its actual parameters. The child then needs to call this function with the parameter. Without any parameters, I can just simply call it. But with a parameter, how can I achieve that? `this.func.apply(null, parm)` would need the child to have another input property to have the parameters.

To generalise this use case, I would like a generic component to delegate part of its functionality to the outside world. An example would be a generic custom input field that delegates its validation to the calling component. The generic custom input field handles all the fancy animations, subscription/broadcast housekeeping etc. And it doesn't care or know how the data should be validated.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a service to me rather than a component.  Why would you need to template programmability?

Comment: Isn't an EventEmitter what you're after? A child component is exposing an event. The parent component subscribes to the child event and executes an event handler (also on the parent).

Comment: @pixelbits That is a good point. Thanks for that. What if I need the return of the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
<app-child [func]="parentFunc(123)"></app-child>
```

Is going to pass the result of calling the function, you would need a seperate input for the paramaters.

```
<app-child [func]="parentFunc" [params]="[123]"></app-child>
```

And you can call it with the spread operator

```
func(...params)
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but as I pointed out that I would not like to have a separate input property for the function parameters.